# Is there a way to get eigenvalues for a particular point in an image?

Tags: c++, opencv, eigenvalue

I am working with OpenCV and inside there is the function [goodFeaturesToTrack](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dd8/tutorial_good_features_to_track.html) to apply ShiTomasi method to find corners.

We know that Shi-Tomasi is based on finding [eigenvalues](https://aishack.in/tutorials/shitomasi-corner-detector/) so there is even a function in OpenCV to calculate the minimal eigenvalue of gradient matrices for corner detection called [`cornerMinEigenVal`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga3dbce297c1feb859ee36707e1003e0a8) in case you want to do your own implementation:

```
void cv::cornerMinEigenVal  (   InputArray      src,
        OutputArray     dst,
        int     blockSize,
        int     ksize = 3,
        int     borderType = BORDER_DEFAULT 
    )
```

However this function finds the minimum eigenvalue for *ALL points* in the image (and store the results in `dst`).

My question is:

Is there a function (in OpenCV or if not any other C++ library) to find the `eigenvalues` (or its minimum) for a particular point `(X,Y)` of an image (and not evaluated in the whole image) (with a blocksize) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: There is no such function in OpenCV that calculate MinEigenVals for sparse points. However, you can implement one from [HarrisResponses()](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/features2d/src/orb.cpp#L131) with just small modifications.

The `HarrisResponses()` function is used to calculate Harris score for sparse points (it's static in OpenCV, so you can't call it directly).

Look through the code of [calcMinEigenVal()](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/imgproc/src/corner.cpp#L98) and [calcHarris()](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/imgproc/src/corner.cpp#L152), and you will find that the only difference between them is how they use values from the `cov` matrix:

```cpp
// MinEigenVal
float a = cov[j*3]*0.5f;
float b = cov[j*3+1];
float c = cov[j*3+2]*0.5f;
dst[j] = (float)((a + c) - std::sqrt((a - c)*(a - c) + b*b));
```

```cpp
// Harris
float a = cov[j*3];
float b = cov[j*3+1];
float c = cov[j*3+2];
dst[j] = (float)(a*c - b*b - k*(a + c)*(a + c));
```

Just change [this line](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/features2d/src/orb.cpp#L169) to:

```cpp
// scale_sq = scale * scale
pts[ptidx].response = (float)((a + b)*0.5f - stb::sqrt((a - b)*(a - b)*0.25f + c*c))*scale_sq;
```

and you will get what you need.